# When should the [*-series] tags be created?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently found out that there are tags like [legend-of-zelda-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-zelda-series), [grand-theft-auto-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-series) and [half-life-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-series), and I was wondering:

- When should the [*-series] tags be created?
- What if there is only a single question that requires the tag? It should be created on this case?

  - If the answer is no, then how should the question be tagged?
- Should they be requested on Meta or just created as they are needed?

---

<sup>This is related to the [What is the Chronological Order of the Sword Art Online Games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/357166/199843) question that I asked a month ago.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like any other tag, series tags should be created when they're needed in order to tag a question. Specifically, series tags are used for questions about no single game in a series, or about how multiple games are connected; it's a type of tag that's heavily tied to lore. For example:

- questions about the overarching setting in multiple games of a series
- questions about the order a certain series is meant to be played in
- questions about how the plot advances between sequential games of a series

If the question is about the mechanics of multiple games in a series, and the games are so strictly tied together for the question to not be closed as "too broad", the game series should not be used, and instead the games should all be tagged.